# git, GitHub, Git Shell

Tags: git, powershell, github

First time using gits or GitHub.  This is where I'm at:

1. I've made a GitHub account
2. I've made a repository called JavaJavaHangmanGame, currently have it initialized with gitignore(Java) and `README.me`
3. I have the GitHub application and Git shell application downloaded on my computer
4. from my GitHub application I select my repository called JavaJavaHangmanGame and open it in shell
5. this shell is the Windows PowerShell
6. my current path or directory is `C:\Users\Reed\Documents\GitHub\JavaJavaHangmanGame [master]>`
7. I have a `.txt` file named JavaJavaHangmanGameTwo holding all of my source code for my program named JavaJavaHangmanGame.  The path or directory where this `.txt` file is located is, `C:\Users\Reed\workspace\GitHub\JavaJavaHangmanGame`

I'm am trying to get `JavaJavaHangmanGameTwo.txt` into the above repository so a friend can help me edit it.  How do I do this?  As mentioned, I am new to this so please prove step by step examples with answer, as it would not take much for me to get lost.

Answer (score 2):

One of the better step by step guides is located at the location below. Instead of providing the answer to your question, would recommend that you spend 15 minutes on that and you would be comfortable to work with Git and GitHub.

https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

To make it easy as per request. Replace place holder between "< >" with actual values:

On the shell:

```
$ git status [you would see your text file] 
$ git add <filename> 
$ git commit -m <comment>
```

then add the remote repo

```
$ git remote add origin <http://..... .git>
```

Finally push to it:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

Comment: It's a very good guide, I went through it, will no doubt go through it again.  Yet, I'm still having trouble with the above.  Chances are my question is address in this guild.  But I have either missed it and/or it is mentioned in a way that I am not making a needed intuitive leap.  Very interested in learning more about gits but right now I need to get this code to my friend asap.  You provided a good answer.  If you would not also mind helping me with my present task, it would be appreciated...I'm sure I would also learn a great deal from successfully adding this file to my repository.

Comment: So I think this is part of my confusion.  When I enter git status, I get: On branch master ,then, Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. ,then, nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: git rev-parse --show-toplevel what does that tell you. Try moving the file to this location and repeat the steps.

Comment: it shows me my current path/directory, but with inverted forward slashes(\) (i.e. /)

Answer (score 0):

From the GH app, clone the repo into a local folder on your system. GitHub works by changing a local version of the project, then "pushing" those changes to a unified version on the GH servers that everyone sees.

To do what you want, you need to clone, then place place your text files inside the folder you cloned to. Then commit the changes with a useful message, e.g., "Added two files for review", then hit push to send those changes to the server.

Your friend can then pull the files into his local version and work on them.

Comment: When I try to clone it states that this repository has already been added but I can not find a push option, nor do I see any changes in my C drive, app or web account